# compare string to const char* always false

Tags: string, char, compare, fstream, getline

I'm trying to compare a string with a const char*.

```
std::string line;
std::fstream tmpl;
```

I fill the string variable with some input from an fstream file using getline:

```
getline(tmpl, line);
```

and then I want to compare the line with something e.g.:

```
if(line == "$something")
```

for some reason it always returns false.
I tried a lot of different things already but without success (either having it return always false or always true)

Why and how do I fix this issue? Did I miss something? Is getline not the right approach?

**Problem fixed** using `string.find()`. I misused it when I tried different things. However the question about comparing with `==` is still open.

Comment: have you tried to print something like: `std::cout << "[" << line << "]" << std::endl;`? It may help debugging. Also, the `$` is just a part of the string in your example, right?

Comment: Make sure that the line doesn't contain white spaces or any other characters you're missing. As Rubens said, the best thing to do is to output the strings you're trying to compare inside some brackets.

Comment: Wow, nevermind. The result using `std::cout << "[" << line << "]" << std::endl;` is actually `]$something`

Comment: Seems like that thing has been fixed by further trying around. The output is as expected `[$something]` yet still doesn't match `"$something"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Now try the below code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  string sample ="hi";
  string datatoprocess ="";
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      datatoprocess = datatoprocess + line;
    }
  unsigned found = datatoprocess.find(sample);
  if (found!=std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "Record Found";
    myfile.close();
  }
else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I don't quite understand how. I guess it was probably a mistake when using line without initialization.

Comment: you asked to compare a string with the file data...

So i read all the contents of the file and place that into a string.... then from that string i check whether the string to compare is present or NOT....
if it is Present then the Comparison is TRUE else FALSE...
Understand...?

Comment: Oh, I found the error now. I used the string.find in a wrong way. That's why I didn't solve it that way. However that still leaves the question about the comparison itself using `==` open.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to use this:

```
if (strcmp(line,"$something")==0)
```

Comment: In `c++` it is valid to compare strings using `==` sign, since  because the basic definition of string includes a global `operator==` which actually calls `strcmp`.

Comment: It must be line.c_str() strcmp does not work with std::string.
The result is the same however

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.. i think it will work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  string sample ="hi";
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
    if(line.compare(sample) == 0)
      cout << line << endl;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is starting to make me feel even more frustrated. I tried the code you posted yet the line `cout << line << endl;` has never been executed...